# Nested SQL Query with verifying the outstanding amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables.

Table 1: Invoice_Number, Amount, OutStanding_Amount

Table 2: Id, Amount

Table 3: Id, Amount

Table 4: Id, Text, Number, Invoice_Number

Example Data:

Table 1:

```
    1001, 5000,3000
```

Table 2:

```
     6, 2000
     10,1000
```

Table 3:

```
     8, 2000
```

Table 4:

```
     1,Table_2,6,1001
     2,Table_3,8,1001
     3, Table_2,10,1001
```

OutStanding Amount = Amount(Invoice) - Amount(Table2)- Amount(Table3) all for same invoice number of course.

Query should output the Corrected OutStanding Amount.
In this case Correct OutStanding Amount is 0 rather then 3000.
Please Note that It might be possible that there are no entry of that Invoice Number in one of the tables (i.e. in table 2 or table 3).

Concept:

1. Going through each row in table 1.
2. Picking all row from table 4 where Invoice number = Invoice number from table1.
3. Getting sum(Amount) from table 2 entries where Text= 'Table 2' retrieved from rows in step 2 and id = id (retrieved from step2 ).
4. Getting sum(Amount) from table 3 entries from id retrieved from rows where Text = 'Table 3' in step 2  and id = id(retrived from step2 ).
5. Adding both those amount and subtracting from Amount in table 1 which we got in step 1.
6. check same with outstanding amount, if different then output the corrected OutStanding amount and Invoice number.

How can I convert this idea into a proper SQL Query to get the desired output?

Comment: Proper SQL would be to drop the column "outstanding amount" and just calculate the value when you need it. How is it even possible that you have a wrong number there? Something like that should never be possible.

Comment: @Solarflare Okey. Let's say I dropped the OutStanding Amount column.Then how can I calculate the outstanding amt in sql query format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just query based out of Invoice Number

```
select t1.invoice_number,Case WHEN t1.Outstanding_amount=(t1.amount-t2.amount-t3.amount) Then t1.Outstanding_amount ELSE  (t1.amount-t2.amount-t3.amount) from table_1 t1 
join table_4 t4 on t1.Invoice_number=t4.Invoice_number
Join table_2 t2 on t4.text=t2.ID
Join Table_3 t3 on t4.text=t3.id where t1.Invoice_number='1001'
```